# ROOT_EFFECTS_INIT is never called

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have an effect in ngrx called `SelfEffect`

I want it to do the following when loaded :

```
  @Effect()
  init$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ROOT_EFFECTS_INIT),
    concatMap(() => of().pipe(withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(IsAuthenticated))))),
    switchMap(([_, isLogged]) => (isLogged ? of(new GetSelfRequest()) : EMPTY))
  );
```

Now, this effect is registered in `app.store.module`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot(appReducers, { metaReducers }),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([AuthEffects, AlertEffects, SelfEffects]),
    StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot({
      serializer: RouterSerializer,
      navigationActionTiming: NavigationActionTiming.PostActivation,
    }),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      name: 'Dev'
     }),
  ],
  providers: [Store],
})
```

which is called in `app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    AppStoreModule,
    ...
  ]
```

Why does this event never dispatch ? is it because I use a router store ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the

```
of().pipe(withLatestFrom)
```

The empty `of()` will never emit an event, therefore the `withLatestFrom` cannot emit either.

The whole line can be simplified to a single `switchMapTo` (`concatMap` is dangerous in the case the `ROOT_EFFECTS_INIT` could fire more times - it would multiply the action each time).

```
  @Effect()
  init$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ROOT_EFFECTS_INIT),
    switchMapTo(this.store.pipe(select(IsAuthenticated))),
    switchMap((isLogged) => (isLogged ? of(new GetSelfRequest()) : EMPTY))
  );
```

PS: I'd consider adding `take(1)` somewhere (depends on what you want to achieve) into the pipe(s) so you have complete control on what is happening.